# Ajax / HTML5 history states (popState, pushState, etc) - back button behavior

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, browser-history, pushstate

There have been several questions about the `pushState` functionality of HTML5, but I'm not able to find anything about two issues I'm having. My `popstate` handler is defined like so:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function (e) {
    if (!e.originalEvent.state)
        return;

    LoadContent({ url: e.originalEvent.state.path });
}
```

The `LoadContent` call simply fills a content pane using ajax.

**Problem 1:** Lets imagine that we start off at `page1` of my site by browsing to it. `LoadContent` won't be called since there is no `state`. Let's imagine that my browsing history is like so:

```
page1 -> (ajax)page2 -> (ajax)page3 -> (back pressed)page2 -> (back pressed)page1
```

When I press the browser's back button to go to `page2`, everything is fine. However, when I press back again, which should load the content for `page1`, `e.originalEvent.state` is *null*, meaning LoadContent won't be called and so the content will remain the same as on `page2`. How can I get `page1`'s content to load when pressing back?

**Problem 2:** Imagine we press back from `page3` to `page2`, which means we load the 2nd page's content through ajax. Now imagine, we **browse** (ie, put in the URL manually into the browser's address bar) to `page3` again, and **then** press back again to go to `page2`. Instead of showing the 2nd page, the browser will instead show just the **ajax results** of `page2`'s content that we retrieved earlier, so that the rest of the page is not loaded. How can this be fixed?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For your problem 1:

You need to either reload the entire page or load it back via ajax, because the data in the initial page will not be pushed to the history. Or else you could change your page load event to load the data from ajax and load the contents dynamically, then you will have the necessary json data that needs to be pushed to the history.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue as your **Problem 2**.

You can send HTTP headers to prevent the web browser from caching and displaying the XHR content. Do this on the page that executes your History object JS.

In PHP:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```